# Is ridge vent wrongly installed or damaged?

Tags: roof, ventilation

We recently had a roofing company do a subpar job installing a new roof.  I noticed that the ridge vent isn't completely flush with the shingles (plastic wavy from left to right).

Question :

1. Is this ridge vent properly installed?[image]

**EDIT : **

Per the comments, I've added an image of the top view of the ridge vent for the sake of identifying the ridge vent.  The top view is of a **different** damaged piece (which was **replaced**).  But you can see that the vent part is from the tray.

[image: top view]

Comment: It sure doesn't look level. Hard to tell exactly what's going on without a closer look at a slightly higher level. Have you taken a look at the ridge vent area from the inside?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "level".  That type of ridge vent is meant to stick above the roof by a couple of inches in order to allow for air flow.

Comment: It is over our dining room and there is no attic over the dining room, just finished ceiling.

Comment: @SteveSh By "level" I mean that in the first photo, the base of the plastic venting is not flat, but is wavy, arcing up and down from left to right. The roof itself seems flat from left to right in that area, so that indicates to me a problem with the vent installation.

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrome Could you clarify what you mean by "isn't completely flush with the shingles"?  I'm by no means an expert on roofing and wonder if you might be better off hiring a professional to fully evaluate it in person. If the installers are already known to have made errors, better to identify other errors now rather than 10 years from now.

Comment: Maybe a better title for this question for would be "Ridge Vent Not Even (or Level) with Peak of Roof".